# Will a 6x10 glue-lam be suitable to replace a 4x10 porch beam with one fewer post?

Tags: structural

I have a 12x15 covered patio. The builder used a 4x10-16 beam supported by three 4x4 posts. Due to some rot issues I need to replace the beam and would like to eliminate the center post. Would a 6x10-16 glulam supported by two 4x6 posts handle the load?

Comment: You would need to provide the load you want to support... without knowing some information about the existing header (the species, the condition, how many are stacked together, etc) there's no way to even tell what the glulam equivalent would be... Add some photos of the existing and provide your local building code information to start down the path of determining minimum design load requirements. It's not as simple as whether the glulam works, you'll need to figure out if going from three posts to two will be enough (probably, but need to look at the whole load transfer).

Comment: Usually to extend unsupported length, you need to increase the depth of the beam/header, instead of the width(4x10 to 4x12 or more).  Or could add another post and have two posts at around 4 or 5 feet from ends.  Are you counting both ends plus centre post as three posts?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, using a 5 1/8” x 10 1/2” glulam beam will support a 16’ long header. You don’t give all the loading information required, but I’ll make some assumptions and you tell me if I’m wrong.

Loading from your covered patio is 20 psf snow live load plus 10 psf dead load (lumber, roofing, etc.) for a total load of 30 psf. Because the covered patio is 12’ deep, then 6’ bears on the header... so, 6’ x 30 psf = 180 plf along the header.

The 5 1/8” x 10 1/2” glulam will support 600 plf. Therefore, 600 plf - 180 plf = 420 plf allowed from the “house side” on the header. So if the span onto the header is less than 28’ then the glulam will support the load. (Remember, 14’ will rest on the new header and the other 14’ will rest on the other side of the house.)

If you live in a climate that has more than 20 psf of snow, the header will still work if snow lasts less than 90 days, due to an impact allowance.

Also, you may use a 4x4 for support at each end in lieu of the 4x6 you’re suggesting. Bearing value on each 4x4 is 600 lbs. x 16’/2 = 4800 lbs. So actual load is 4800 lbs. / 3.5” x 3.5” = 391 psi. ~ 385 psi allowable.

Make sure the beam and posts are connected together with a metal connector, such as Simpson ACE.

Likewise, connect the post base to the sole plate with a metal connector.

The last issue to check is bearing on footings. The code allows 1500 psf soil bearing value without a geotechnical report. Therefore, the maximum loading on the soil is 4800 lbs. plus 600 lbs. of concrete for a total load of 5,400 lbs.  If your footings are a minimum of 16” wide, then you’d need only the perimeter strip footing to be a minimum of 30” long.

When you order your glulam, be sure to order 2400 f. (Not 2200 f.)

Comment: I would note that while a 4x4 post would work (I'm not questioning the math - far beyond my skills), a 4x6 would match up to the beam's width and aesthetically look better, IMHO, than a 4x4 under a 6x beam.

Comment: @FreeMan You’re probably right, except the 4x6 post would have a depth of 5 1/2” and the glulam would have a depth of 5 1/8” depth. I guess the 4x6 could be ripped down to 5 1/8” to match the glulam. Also, I was thinking that the 4x4 posts would “fit” back into the original wall and maybe the wallboard board would cover the new posts. Then, only the new beam would protrude beyond the thickness of the wall.

Comment: Thank you all for your feedback it is very, very helpful.

Answer (score -1):

No. Your proposed beam will not work, as well as the posts and the foundation.

A simple comparison, eliminating the mid-post in a two continuous spans setup (assuming the span lengths are equal), the resulting moment demand is 4 times as great as the original. For the new beam to be able to survive, from the strength point of view, it needs a section modulus 4 times as large as the original 4 x10, that is

4 x S1 = S2, in which S1 = b1 x h1^2 = 4*16^2/6 = 170.67 in^3, and S2 = 6*h2^2/6 = h2^2 in^3

Thus, h2^2 = 4*170.67 ---> h2 = 26.13" >> 16"

Further evaluation is required to examine the impact of the increased support reactions that is likely to call for upsizing of the posts and foundations. Also, the elimination of the mid-post will result in increased deflection that may require further upsizing the beam.

Comment: This answer is all bunk. There is so much wrong with this answer, I have to downvote it. First, why assume the moment and section modules is 4 times the original? Why not calculate the actual moment? Second, glulam beams are not the same size as cut timbers. Why use cut timbers sizes.